# Owncloud disappear from my server

Tags: mysql, centos, owncloud

I have an owncloud installation in my cloud server. Yesterday it was all ok.
But when I reboot my server (CentOS 6.3) I tried to access owncloud on the web. But it's not there.
I checked my owncloud folder and is empty. The owncloud database (in Mysql) doesn't exists.
As I said, before the reboot it was all ok. But right now I think I lost everything.

I know that it's not a lot of information, but it's all that I have.

If anybody can help me to find out what happen, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that my Ispconfig instance rewrite some of the virtualhosts configuration and that's why it was pointing to other folder.